# How to know which URL is accessed from IP address/Country in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

How to find-out which url is accessed from which IP address/Country using Google analytic.

I found the country list and visit count. how do i know which URL visited from that country.

Answer (score 1):

Create an advanced segment for
    visitors from the country you're
    interested from, then choose only
    that segment in your 'Content'
    reports and view the pages accessed
    by users from this country.

**Steps to follow:**

1. Go to 'Advanced Segments' under 'My
       customizations'
2. Follow the link to '+ Create new
       advanced segment'
3. Drag 'Country/Territory' from
   Dimensions -> Visitors in the left
   hand panel to the segment creation
   panel. In the 'Value' field, choose
   the country. Type in a name for the
   segment and then click 'Create
   segment'
4. Go back to your Google Analytics
   site report. In the upper left hand
   corner open up the 'Advanced
   Segments' tab. Deselect the default
   'All Visits' segment from 'Default
   Segments'. Select your
   country-specific segment from
   'Custom Segments'. Click 'Apply'.
5. Bingo! Now your analytics reports
   are showing the data for visitors
   only from your chosen country. The 'Content' tab on the left where previously you could see lists of pages all your visitors accessed you'll see lists of URLs with visitor stats
   from that country only.

Comment: Thank you!!!, That means there is no default section to display this kind of events like  Country&Visit List => First Column(country lists) second column (URL visited). So that we can calculate which url is popular in which country instead of creating each segment for each country.. right?

Comment: No, there is no standard report to access this sort of information and I'm not sure if it's even possible in GA.

Comment: You can also go to **Site Content -> Pages** and add a secondary dimension: click on **Secondary dimension** and choose **Visitors -> Country / Territory**, as explained here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24855/how-to-see-traffic-from-a-country-to-a-page-in-google-analytics. You can also do an advanced search on those fields if you only want to see visits from a specific country.